# Navbar must appear directly form second div

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

how can I code the js file to directly put the navbar on the second div? Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/paolopolix/pen/NNzrmb), it works but on the first load the navbar is sticked on the top of the site; I don't want it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
     if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#main').outerHeight())
        $('.navbar').removeClass('fixed');
     else
        $('.navbar').addClass('fixed');
  });
});
```

Comment: so you want to display the nav bar only when user scroll down..right?

Comment: yes I need it sticked on the top of the 2nd div and then follow down the user scroll..

Comment: ohh i thought you only wants to show when user scroll or it will be hidden..

Comment: check this one http://codepen.io/avinafh/pen/xVzEwM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `.fixed` class by default to the `nav` element and it works :)

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONERVR)

Comment: I was sure it was already on the nav.. it wasn't! thanks dude! :)